# What's the equivalent of loading a JSON into a dict in Nim

Tags: json, nim-lang

I am new to Nim and I want to read a JSON file to a `dict` style data structure to get access the keys as columns.

```
proc get_url() : string =
    return "train.json"
```

And the parser:

```
var file = get_url()
var json_data = file.parseFile()
var values = newTable() # dict style data structure?

for record in json_data:
 for key, value in record:
   values[key] = value # not
```

Apparently the Table needs to instantiated more specifically.

I don't know the amount of keys in the JSON file. In the manuals it's exemplified as `var a = {"hi": 1, "there": 2}.toTable`. That doesn't seem to be generic enough to parse random JSON files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parsing json using the stdlib's `json` module already gives you a `dict`-style data structure: the `JsonNode`.

The `json` docs explain how to use this fairly well: https://nim-lang.org/docs/json.html#dynamically-retrieving-fields-from-json

Comment: ok, that makes sense. How do I get the keys from that JsonNode. A dict in Python has a simple function for that...

Comment: Just like you would in Python: `myNode["key"]`. This gives you another node, so you need to do something with it depending on what you expect its type to be.